# Implementing Binary Search Tree (Python)

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have the task to perform some basic operations on Binary Search Trees and I'm not sure what is the clever way to do it.

I know that the usual way would be to write a class for the nodes and one for the tree so that I can build up my tree from given values and perform certain tasks on it. The thing is, I'm already getting the tree as a list and since BSTs are not unique, there won't come any good from it if I take each value and build the tree myself.

So... I'm getting a list like this:

```
11 9 2 13 _, 4 18 2 14 _, 2 10 _ 11 4, 14 16 4 _ _, 13 0 11 _ _ | 10 | 7
```

which means:

```
key value parent left right, ... | value1 | value2
```

So as you see the BST is given explicitly. My tasks are to do a level-print of the tree, return the path from `root` to `value1`, do a `rotate-right` operation on the subtree that has `value1`, then `delete value1` and then `insert value2`.

What would be an efficient way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible way of implementing the tree. Hope it helps. Though this contains insertions and popular traversals, not rotations or deletions.

Reference: http://www.thelearningpoint.net/computer-science/learning-python-programming-and-data-structures/learning-python-programming-and-data-structures--tutorial-20--graphs-breadth-and-depth-first-search-bfsdfs-dijkstra-algorithm-topological-search

```
'''
Binary Search Tree is a binary tree(that is every node has two branches), 
in which the values contained in the left subtree is always less than the
root of that subtree, and the values contained in the right subtree is
always greater than the value of the root of the right subtree.
For more information about binary search trees, refer to :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
'''
#Only for use in Python 2.6.0a2 and later
from __future__ import print_function
class Node:

    # Constructor to initialize data
    # If data is not given by user,its taken as None 
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    # __str__ returns string equivalent of Object
    def __str__(self):
        return "Node[Data = %s]" % (self.data,)

class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    '''
    While inserting values in a binary search tree, we first check
    whether the value is greater than, lesser than or equal to the
    root of the tree.
    We initialize current node as the root. 
    If the value is greater than the current node value, then we know that
    its right location will be in the right subtree. So we make the current
    element as the right node.

    If the value is lesser than the current node value, then we know that
    its right location will be in the left subtree. So we make the current
    element as the left node.

    If the value is equal to the current node value, then we know that the
    value is already contained in the tree and doesn't need to be reinserted.
    So we break from the loop.
    '''
    def insert(self, val):
        if (self.root == None):
            self.root = Node(val)
        else:
            current = self.root

            while 1:
                if (current.data > val):
                    if (current.left == None):
                        current.left = Node(val)
                        break
                    else:
                        current = current.left

                elif (current.data < val):
                    if (current.right == None):
                        current.right = Node(val)
                        break
                    else:
                        current = current.right

                else:
                    break
    '''
    In preorder traversal, we first print the current element, then
    move on to the left subtree and finally to the right subree.
    '''
    def preorder(self, node):
        if (node == None):
            return
        else:
            print(node.data, end=" ")
            self.preorder(node.left)
            self.preorder(node.right)
    '''
    In inorder traversal, we first move to the left subtree, then print
    the current element and finally move to the right subtree.
    '''

    #Important : Inorder traversal returns the elements in sorted form.
    def inorder(self, node):
        if (node == None):
            return
        else:
            self.inorder(node.left)
            print(node.data, end=" ")
            self.inorder(node.right)
    '''
    In postorder traversal, we first move to the left subtree, then to the
    right subtree and finally print the current element.
    '''
    def postorder(self, node):
        if (node == None):
            return
        else:
            self.postorder(node.left)
            self.postorder(node.right)
            print(node.data, end=" ")

tree = BinarySearchTree()
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(9)
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(5)
tree.insert(7)
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(0)
print ("Preorder Printing")
tree.preorder(tree.root)
print("\n\nInorder Printing")
tree.inorder(tree.root)
print("\n\nPostOrder Printing")
tree.postorder(tree.root)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation of Binary Search Tree with it's basic operations like insert node, find node

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    def set_root(self,data):
        self.root = Node(data)
    def insert_node(self,data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.set_root(data)
        else:
            n = Node(data)
            troot = self.root
            while troot:
                if data < troot.data:
                    if troot.left:
                        troot = troot.left
                    else:
                        troot.left = n
                        break
                else:
                    if troot.right:
                        troot = troot.right
                    else:
                        troot.right = n
                        break
    def search_node(self,data):
        if self.root is None:
            return "Not found"
        else:
            troot = self.root
            while troot:
                if data < troot.data:
                    if troot.left:
                        troot = troot.left
                        if troot.data == data:
                            return "Found"
                    else:
                        return "Not found"
                elif data > troot.data:
                    if troot.right:
                        troot = troot.right
                        if troot.data == data:
                            return "Found"
                    else:
                        return "Not found"
                else:
                    return "Found"

tree = BST()
tree.insert_node(10)
tree.insert_node(5)
tree.insert_node(20)
tree.insert_node(7)

print(tree.root.data)
print(tree.root.left.data)
print(tree.root.right.data)
print(tree.root.left.right.data)

print(tree.search_node(10))
print(tree.search_node(5))
print(tree.search_node(20))
print(tree.search_node(7))
print(tree.search_node(12))
print(tree.search_node(15))
```

Output:

```
10
5
20
7
Found
Found
Found
Found
Not found
Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case I had success using a dictionary as a datatype to store the graph. The key is the node_key and the value is a list with the attributes of the node. In this way it is rather fast to find the needed nodes and all its attributes.

I'm just not sure if there is a way to make it reasonably faster.